# A comparaison between 2 equal variables returns false in Google script (sheets)

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I hope you can help me in this mind blowing problem I have:

Well, I have 2 different arrays (cam and existentes). The [2] value of existentes is the same string than the [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMPEJ.png) value of cam. But when I try to compare `existentes [2] == cam [1]` it returns a False.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Solution:

You are comparing two **arrays**: `[Remarketing] == [Remarketing]` while you should be comparing two **strings** `Remarketing == Remarketing`:

```
existentes[2][0]==cam[1][0]
```

### Minimal Reproducible Example:

```js
  const ar1 = ["Remarketing"];
  const ar2 = ["Remarketing"];
  console.log(ar1==ar2); // returns false
  console.log(ar1[0]==ar2[0]); // returns true
```

In case you had arrays with multiple elements you wanted to compare, then you can read this post on how to compare two arrays in `JavaScript`:

[How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)